# Problem grub won't display on my tv at boot up

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, resolution

When I start my computer it won't show my grub screen this box just appears saying something along the lines of "this tv cannot handle this resolution or refresh rate" but after a couple seconds it brings me to the log in screen. Any idea what exactly the problem is and how do I fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You more then likely can not fix it.

TVs are notoriously bad for supporting PC resolutions, some only support 1 or two "main" resolutions and others support only their TV native resolution.

For example my TV only supports 1024x768 if you use the VGA cable, even though it's a 720p TV.

To correct this, you can force grub and Linux  VTYs to use a specific VGA mode that you know your TV will support.

Basically: (file names and locations might change, depends on config)

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=vesafb:mtrr:2"
>   ....
>   GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
>   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=KEEP

Then update grub and add the device to your initramfs

`sudo update-grub2`
`echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash`
`sudo update-initramfs -u`

[More Information here](http://danipavliashvili2.blogspot.com/2011/06/ubuntu-server-changing-screen.html)